# Ruby on Rails web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm new to web development, and have a question about deploy ruby on rails application.

For what i'm understanding, there are two ways to deploy. One is using cloud server like Heroku (I'm currently using). You just need to upload your project to their cloud server and ready to go.

Another way is build your own server using, for example, apache+passenger. By doing this way, I need to have a physical computer with Ubuntu + Apache + Passenger running continually right?

So my question is which way is better, faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) has a form of automated deployment built-in. There are other cloud-based providers which offer a similar sort of service.

The alternative is self-hosted. You don't need a "physical computer", you can use a virtualized server in the cloud just the same. Popular choices are [Linode](http://linode.com/), [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com/) and [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) which is what Heroku is based on.

"Better" is highly subjective. Do you know how to maintain a server? If the answer to this question is "No", then Heroku is probably the best bet.

If you do know how to maintain a server, you can usually get better performance from your own rig since you have full control over how your application is launched, how long it stays running, and can increase resources at marginal additional cost. The downside is you're responsible for everything should it malfunction.

Comment: Great Thanks. I'd better choose something like Heroku. The only problem with Heroku I'm facing is the latency. In some country, there will be about 500ms lag.

Comment: Some cloud providers allow you to choose the datacentre you want to host the application in. Amazon has [facilities in many countries](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/globalinfrastructure/?nc1=h_l2_cc) but I'm not sure which Heroku allows you to deploy in.

Comment: There's probably a bunch, but Heroku and [EngineYard](http://engineyard.com/) are the two biggest ones. They're both built on top of Amazon EC2, but EngineYard can use Teramark for bare hardware if you like that better and can afford it. The cost goes up dramatically for dedicated hardware.